# swift extension func with generic type - isEmpty for FetchedResults

Tags: swift, generics

I am having some trouble implementing an extension func to determine whether or not an entity contains any results. The end goal is to determine if an entity has results or not, and seed them in at app launch if not (for certain entities like a Country list, etc...)

Here is where I was able to get, but the swift compiler is not happy; error: Type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchRequestResult'

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    func isEmpty<T>(context: NSManagedObjectContext, entityName: String, entityType: T.Type) -> Bool {
        do {
            let fetch = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: entityName)
            let count = try context.fetch(fetch)
            return count == 0 ? true : false
        } catch {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to restrict `T` to be an `NSManagedObject` subclass.
You should also use `count(for:)` if you are only interested in the
number of objects:

```
func isEmpty<T: NSManagedObject>(context: NSManagedObjectContext, entityName: String, entityType: T.Type) -> Bool {
    do {
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: entityName)
        let count = try context.count(for: fetch)
        return count == 0
    } catch {
        return true
    }
}
```

But actually you don't need that parameter:

```
func isEmpty(context: NSManagedObjectContext, entityName: String) -> Bool {
    do {
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        let count = try context.count(for: fetch)
        return count == 0
    } catch {
        return true
    }
}
```

As a performance improvement you can also set

```
        fetch.fetchLimit = 1
```

*Remark:* A statement

```
return someBooleanCondition ? true : false
```

can (and should) always be simplified to

```
return someBooleanCondition
```